# Which MySQL Workbench version support windows xp 32 bit?

Tags: windows-xp, version, mysql-workbench

I'm developing software for windows xp I want to install `MySQL Workbench`
which version support windows xp 32 bit?

Comment: Every build after April 2014 https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html

Comment: Pages are not available about win xp EOL

Comment: That is only the link to Microsoft - You don't need a page that tells you XP is EOL - you should know that you are riding a long-dead horse. The important information is `Per the MySQL Support Lifecycle policy regarding ending support for OS versions that are obsolete or have reached end of life, we plan to discontinue building all MySQL binaries for Microsoft Windows XP as of April 8, 2014.`

Comment: Thank you so much for attention and time.